# Android studio IDE automatically stops after Startup

Tags: android-studio

My Android studio IDE always stops whenever I start it.it boots very well, but few minutes after it shows me my activities and build environment,it automatically stops.
This issue has been prevalent in my previous android studio version which always Bubblebee.Now am using Android studio Dolphin version and still experience same thing

I have uninstalled and installed a new version and still no improvement.

Comment: Yes, I'm also facing this issue for a few seconds. Android studio gets stuck for a few seconds when it starts. I'm facing this issue only in the Dolphin version.

Comment: Check Windows Event Viewer if there is actually any exception occuring. And delete .gradle , .android  and Android SDK folders too